# Fetching data from multiple tables using EF and .NET

Tags: entity-framework

I have 2 entities that store transactional data and are related using `studentid`

- E1 : { id, studentid, teacher, count }
- E2 : { id, studentid, teacher, time }

I wish to get this data into a list.

I tried using

```
List<RawDataDTO> model = (from t in _context.e1 
                          join s in _context.e2 on t.studentid equals s.studentid
                          where (t.studentid == request.Id) 
                          select new RawDataDTO
                                 {
                                     Id = t.studentid,
                                     TeacherName = t.teacher,              
                                     Count = t.count,
                                     Time = **s.**time
                                 }).ToList();
return model;
```

How do I get records from `e2` also populated in the model?